# show message to specific day with repetition

Tags: ios, timer, alertview

I want to always display a certain day one Alert view, for example, should always come 8.00 Note the clock on Monday .... so if I state the app and it's Monday 9:00 you will get the alert view, and every Monday

my code to determine the day is:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSLog([f stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

has an idea how to make it someone

thanks jürgen

Answer (score 0):

Use Local-Notification in IOS to  show alert view in give time with user information.
follow the link..
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=292